# WPF MVVM Custom Validation : Need to show red border row based on Sort Test Pass on a particular column in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm, datagrid

Here is the situation. I am using Commands to bind to Execution logic, but I need to validate if the particular column of the DataGrid is sorted, throw a popup alert to user and based on his choice (Resort: Yes/No?) either resort or highlight the DataGrid rows (which are out of order).

Suggest me how to implement this. Stating clearly whether it should be in **view-model** or **codebehind**.

Scenario:My dataGrid ItemSource is bound to an Observable collection of my viewModel and i am checking the date column for sorting

VIEW MODEL Based approach
I have a ViewModel as shown with the following command

```
public void Calculate()
    {
           //Need to pass instance of DataGRid to manipulate
           //do something

            if (GridValidations.CheckValidationOnCalculate(this))
            {


            }
     }


CheckValidation(ViewmMdel viewModelInstance)
{
//viewModelInstance.IngestedDataGrid Property
//Check if not sorted
                 //Display with red border 


}
```

Code Behind based approach 
OR i could Add a Code behind file setting the red border of DataGridRow 
since i can easily iterate over the ObservableCollection bound to View here as well

OR if you have a better solution in mind please speak up.

Comment: Sounds like homework...just kidding. ;o) Well, since we won't provide you some code without seeing, what you've already achieved or tried, you will have to do it on your own. SO is not a code factory a la "This is the input and that's what I need." Actually, it wouldn't not help you, anyway, since the solution may be incompatible to your current architecture. If you have one...